# How to pass error back to caller function using async?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, error-handling

right now i am throwing error if "dateofBirth" is not found that just sent empty object back to client , how can i pass error object back to client instead of empty object. basically want to send back to process catch

main.ts

```
export class GetSpecialtyQuestionsController extends Controller {
        public static async process(@Request() request: ExpressRequest,
            response: ExpressResponse): Promise < any > {
            try {
                const instance = new GetSpecialtyQuestionsController();
                const data = await instance.execute(request);
                response.status(200);
                response.send(data);
            } catch (err) {
                response.status(200);
                response.send(err.message);
            }

        }

        // private _request: IRequestURL[] = [];

        constructor() {
            super();
        }

        private async execute(@Request() request: ExpressRequest): Promise < any > {
            // const specialtyMembers = this.getSpecialtyMemberInfoFakeObject();
            const specialtyMembers = await new SpecialtyCacheUtility().getSpecialtyMemberInfoCache(
                request.body.getSpecialtyQuestionsRequest.header.serviceContext.tokenID);
            if (!specialtyMembers) {
                return this.errorHandler(request);
            }
            let proxyMember: ISpecialtyInfoObj = {}
            as ISpecialtyInfoObj;
            for (const member of specialtyMembers) {
                if (member.specialtyIdEnc === request.body.getSpecialtyQuestionsRequest.details.specialtyIdEnc) {
                    proxyMember = member;
                    if (!member.dateOfBirth) {
                        throw new Error('no patient info for given HBS ID');
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: i tried its still returning empty object {} to UI and showing error in network response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your custom exception object to pass data while throw error

```
class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor(foo = 'bar', ...params) {
    // Pass remaining arguments (including vendor specific ones) to parent constructor
    super(...params);

    // Maintains proper stack trace for where our error was thrown (only available on V8)
    if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
      Error.captureStackTrace(this, CustomError);
    }

    // Custom debugging information
    this.foo = foo;
    this.date = new Date();
  }
}

try {
  throw new CustomError('baz', 'bazMessage');
} catch(e){
  console.log(e.foo); //baz
  console.log(e.message); //bazMessage
  console.log(e.stack); //stacktrace
}
```

For reference read more from official mdn documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: i wanted to send object like `return {
   header: {
    statusCode: REQUEST_SYSTEM_FAILURE,
    statusDesc: REQUEST_FAILURE_STATUS_DESCRIPTION,
    refID: request.body.getSpecialtyQuestionsRequest.header.serviceContext.refID,
    tokenID: request.body.getSpecialtyQuestionsRequest.header.serviceContext.tokenID
   }`

Comment: Where do you want to send object?.  Set your object in the `throw new CustomError(YOUR_CUSTOM_OBJECT, 'bazMessage');` and get it in the catch of parent function.